# How can I run a WebSocket server on top of GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, websocket

How can I run a WebSocket server on top of Google App Engine? Is it possible? Will it be possible?

Comment: From 2010 to 2013 lots of things have changed. See Channel https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/?csw=1

Comment: @JosepValls, Is that solution built on top of the WebSocket standard or is it a Google-specific technology?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Is it possible?**

No.

You can't right now because GAE doesn't allow generic inbound socket connections. Each request is also limited to 30 seconds but this could easily be worked around with automatic reconnection and session tracking.

**Will it be possible?**

Probably.

Google has been one of the biggest (main) promoters of the WebSockets standard. I would be surprised if they don't push support for it into GAE at some point in the future. Note that the WebSockets draft standard is still in flux so Google might be hesitant to add support before the standard is more solid.

Here is the bug for WebSockets support on GAE: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2535

Note that a google employee indicates it's not on the roadmap but that they know it would be useful. That's about as positive an answer as you get from google about features that have not been announced. I recommend adding your voice to that bug in favor of WebSocket support. It can't hurt.

Also, depending on your application, you may consider the Channel API which will likely have GAE support soon:

- http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/05/app-engine-at-google-io-2010.html
- http://bitshaq.com/2010/09/01/sneak-peak-gae-channel-api/

**EDIT (2015)**: the Channels API is available now (it has been for a while).

Comment: I am not able to create channel on client side. Can you please answer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332222/unable-to-create-new-channel-in-javascript-of-channel-api

Answer (score 19):

*All of these answers are out of date.*

The Channel API has been [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/channel). Google **strongly** recommends you use [Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio).

It is also worth noting, that Google has now released the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).

With the flexible environment, you could easily allow socket connections, or use Python 3.

Comment: I think flexible environment is basically running your own compute engine so it would most likely work... and probably what I would go for... however you would need one running 24/7 (about £50/yr for the smallest VM)

Comment: I can confirm that sockets on the Flexible Environment do work. Tested with socket.io and no special configuration required.

Answer (score 10):

It's officially supported now.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/

**EDIT**: the Channel API is supported, not WebSockets. The Channel API is built on WebSockets, but it doesn't give you direct access to the WebSocket. I suppose it's good enough for typical Web apps.

Comment: For posterity, the Channels API is only frontend->backend. It's no good for server->server connections.

Comment: It's also being sunset and will stop working as of 2017-10-31: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/channel

Answer (score 4):

As of January 9, 2019 it is officially in Beta now - but only for App Engine **flexible**. For example, see the [Python documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity). According to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348#comment270), it will work with any language, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

GAE limits HTTP requests to 30 seconds, WebSockets expect to have connection open for a long time.

Will it be possible? Only Google knows this.

Comment: The 30 second request limit isn't really a major blocker. It would be easy to create a layer that starts a new WebSockets connection for the same session before the old request expires so that you would never have any gaps in the communication. Only allowing inbound HTTP requests is the real killer.

Comment: Websockets are two way (as is HTTP) but they are started inbound only (from client to server). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets

Comment: And GAE is also outbound: use URL Fetch

Answer (score 2):

A couple people have gotten websockets working with GAE with the help of another server... checkout http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/wiki/WebSockets

Answer (score 1):

There's also this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/
It's experimental and very low level though.

Comment: "Sockets are available only for paid apps.
You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets."

Comment: @demented hedgehog, do you know of the part about only creating outbound sockets will allow me to send real time updates to the users on front end.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine has recently launched support for Websockets on App Engine Flexible Environment. You can take a look at their blog post.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-websockets-support-for-app-engine-flexible-environment

Answer (score 1):

**June 2019**

Websocket support for GAE is now supported under SLA for Flex.

```
Hi everyone, I'm happy to announce that Websockets support 
for Flex is now Generally Available! We've made no changes since Beta 
but Websockets traffic is now subject to our SLA. 

We've also published documentation for this feature for all App Engine Flex languages.
```

See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348#comment285

Answer (score 0):

Hope helps, but seems to be supported now. 2021
[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-websockets-and-session-affinity][1]