# running websocket in google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, websocket

I use API Endpoint in my app script google sheet but some time, I get this Error :

```
{"code":-1003,"msg":"Way too much request weight used; IP banned until 1632924884440. Please use the websocket for live updates to avoid bans."}
```

Any Solution for that problem, I read A lot of content but there are says this is able to do websocket and another article says not able to do websocket in google sheet. If I don't able to do it, There are another solutions for that??

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370977/google-app-scripts-and-websocket

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121920/how-can-i-create-a-websocket-on-google-app-engine-for-html5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try with Binance for example. You can use websocket in an html file. It means that you can create a sidebar with this html file and transfer information with it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body{margin:12px;}
  </style>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var wsUri = ("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws");
  <? var myparam = param(); ?>
  var nbr=0
  
  function init()  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
    nbr=0;
  }

  function onOpen(evt)  {
    writeLog("Connected to:<br>" + wsUri);
    doSend(<?= myparam ?>);
  }

  function onClose(evt)  {
    writeLog("Disconnected from:<br>" + wsUri);
  }

  function onMessage(evt)  {
    nbr++;
    google.script.run.getJSON( evt.data );
    document.getElementById('nbr').innerHTML=('<span style="color: blue;">Response #<b>' + nbr + '</b> transmitted to sheet</span>');
  }

  function onError(evt)  {
    writeLog('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)  {
    writeLog("Sent: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeLog(message)  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById("log").appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", websocket.close, false);
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nbr">&nbsp;</div><br>
  <div id="lastButtonBlock" class="block">
    <button onclick="init()" class ="action button actionButton" >&nbsp;Connect&nbsp;</button>
    <button onclick="websocket.close()" class ="action button actionButton" >&nbsp;Disconnect&nbsp;</button>
    <button onclick="google.script.host.close()" class ="create deleteButton actionButton" >&nbsp;Close&nbsp;</button>
  </div><br>
  <div id="log"></div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

the gs file will be for instance

```
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('derCotation');

function param(){
  var valeurs = sh.getRange('B3:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().join().split(",")
  var myparams = {"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": valeurs, "id": 1}
  return JSON.stringify(myparams) 
}

function getJSON(jsonstring){
  try{
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
    var pairs = sh.getRange('A3:A').getValues().join().split(",");
    var ligne = pairs.indexOf(data.k.s);
    if (ligne != -1){
      var result=[]
      result.push([ data.k.o , data.k.c , data.k.h , data.k.l ])
      sh.getRange('C' + (ligne+3) + ':F' + (ligne+3)).setValues(result)
    }
  }
  catch(e){
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I run It, After open spreadsheet without clicking in any button. after sleep my computer the websocket Disconnect why??? I want to run without Disconnect. can Disconnect after close spreadsheet.

Comment: I can't answer to that question, please refer to the binance documentation. What is your API EndPoint ? You didn't answer to Cooper request to provide a complete minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This URL: `https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#24hr-ticker-price-change-statistics` Endpoint is /api/v3/ticker/price

Comment: And run websocket without click to any button just after open spreadsheet. means running  hidden .

Comment: The url you provide is not a complete minimal reproducible example! To lunch and stop automatically you can add in the script : `window.addEventListener("load", init, false)` and `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", websocket.close, false)`

Comment: Yes This is what I need lunch and stop automatically. I'm new in Developer . Can You Write it as code in the code above Please & add can I run it every time without stop websocket after close spreadsheet.

Comment: Done, take a new copy of the spreadsheet.

Comment: This method work if I'm open slidebare web socket but not this what I need. so you can run websocket first time after give Authenticate to script. but not every time we need to open slidebare to run websocket, this method is not good. and I tell you if I run it without stope after first run.

Comment: Thx for your feed-back. I give you another solution as you requested. I have spent a while to do that. You can now transpose in a web browser if you want.  That's all for me. I think that i have responded to `running websocket in google sheet`