# running websocket in google sheet without using HTML code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, websocket

I find this test for Binance websocket in app script the code in this URL:

[running websocket in google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378549/running-websocket-in-google-sheet/69382528#69382528)

I want to remove code HTML and run websocket without using HTML code.

I want just use:

```
  

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('BINANCE')
    .addItem('RUN', 'runwebsocket')
    .addToUi();
  
}
```

to run websocket

any suggest for the problem .

Comment: I don't think it is possible! Whenever it could be possible, you will be imited by 6 mn (google script limit).

Comment: you tell me this is not possible. so any help for use websocket in google sheet? or can I run websocket from side bar and then hide side bar without stop websocket

Comment: AFAIK you can't hide the sidebar, except by resizing your browser window and putting the sidebar off your screen! Why do you want to work without the sidebar?

Comment: May be you can create an add-on or use an add-on ... see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vm_u04dceyU

Comment: I want to hide it because has ugly view. I see this video the man using add-on to run it but if I build add-on and run it after close sheet the websocket is keep running or stop.

Comment: okay @MikeSteelson Thanks for explain

Comment: You can use a sidebar solution as a white paper without any information except the title. You can use the sidebar for img, logo or leave it as a blank page. I stopped testing a web application which is not free for this application.

Comment: You can use the sidebar for img! You mean add image inside sidebar?

Comment: yes, in the html file ... it will be less ugly !

Comment: While it's OK to include links to other posts, questions should be self-contained. You should have included the relevant parts of the linked posts and showed what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to embed the html javascript in a blank page

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var wsUri = ("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws");
  <? var myparam = param(); ?>
  
  function init()  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
    nbr=0;
  }

  function onOpen(evt)  {
    doSend(<?= myparam ?>);
  }

  function onClose(evt)  {
  }

  function onMessage(evt)  {
    google.script.run.getJSON( evt.data );
  }

  function onError(evt)  {
  }

  function doSend(message)  {
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", websocket.close, false);
  
  </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

you can lunch this way

```
function modal() {
  var html = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile("index")
    .evaluate()
    .setWidth(100)
    .setHeight(50);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'web socket');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I see some test for using `EventListene`. so to run it you need HTML code. I try to test it not in sidebar I use in showModalDialog but not working. I try to minimaze or resize the sidebar bar this is default

Comment: Great tutorial thanks. the dialog box set in center sheet I try to get it small or change position but  no way. can know any way to do it .

Comment: Can I see the dialog box just in one sheet without see in another sheet?

Comment: no, if you change and select another tab, the dialog box still appear in the front window and will not be hidden

Comment: you can drag the dialog box to the right, see the picture I have added to the answer

Comment: Yeah I drag it manual. so any suggest if I want to build it as a addon-on.