# Why google.script.run not working in onmessage() call in javascript html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, websocket

I am trying to run code provided here:-
[running websocket in google sheet without using HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962365/running-websocket-in-google-sheet-without-using-html-code)

This is the html page-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var wsUri = ("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m");
  <? var myparam = param(); ?>
  
  function init()  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
    nbr=0;
  }

  function onOpen(evt)  {
    //doSend(<?= myparam ?>);
  }

  function onClose(evt)  {
  }

  function onMessage(evt)  {
    google.script.run.getJSON( evt.data );//evt.data is an object
  }

  function onError(evt)  {
  }

  function doSend(message)  {
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", websocket.close, false);
  
  </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

this is app script code calling this client-side JavaScript

```js
function modal() {
  var html = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile("index")
    .evaluate()
    .setWidth(100)
    .setHeight(50);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'web socket');
}
```

These are other functions in same Apps Script -

```js
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('derCotation');

function param(){
  var valeurs = sh.getRange('B3:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().join().split(",")
  var myparams = {"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": valeurs, "id": 1}
  return JSON.stringify(myparams) 
}

function getJSON(jsonstring){//this is receiving an object not a string
  try{
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonstring);//this is parsing an object not a strig
    var pairs = sh.getRange('A3:A').getValues().join().split(",");
    var ligne = pairs.indexOf(data.k.s);
    if (ligne != -1){
      var result=[]
      result.push([ data.k.o , data.k.c , data.k.h , data.k.l ])
      sh.getRange('C' + (ligne+3) + ':F' + (ligne+3)).setValues(result)
    }
  }
  catch(e){
  }
}
```

Script is running but `google.script.run.getJSON( evt.data );` not working. What may be wrong?

I tested for errors but there are not any. I observed that `getJSON()` function here `google.script.run.getJSON( evt.data );` is not being called.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] that would allow us to reproduce the problem

Comment: the function jetJSON() called is not showing the variable values passed to it in the script , tried to show results in Logger.log(jsonstring).

Comment: How do you expect to have anything passed without utilizing a withSuccessHandler?

Comment: I am new to javascript html and running it as it was working for the previous person. who asked about it. Please pardon my ingnorance . Please help. I have updated the whole code here.

Comment: I believe that `evt` is an object and not a json string.  So using JSON.parse() on an object is not what was intended.  JSON.parse() creates an object from a JSON string.

Comment: but passing evt.data not evt.

Comment: Yes but `evt.data` is still an object

Comment: What is displayed in the console when you add `console.log(e);` in the `catch(e)` part of your `function getJSON` and run your script?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function getJSON(data){
  Logger.log(JSON.striingify(data));
  try{
    var pairs = sh.getRange('A3:A' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().join().split(",");
    var ligne = pairs.indexOf(data.k.s);
    if (ligne != -1){
      var result=[]
      result.push([ data.k.o , data.k.c , data.k.h , data.k.l ])
      sh.getRange('C' + (ligne+3) + ':F' + (ligne+3)).setValues(result)
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this `.getValues().join().split(",")`

Comment: it is taking some values from google sheet which i dont need. concern right now is to receive that jsonstring

Comment: my curiosity is that split seems to be just undoing what join does unless there are more commas in the data that I don't know about

Comment: The modification that I made above justs assumes that data is already an object.  But it is possible that this may not work if the data contain restricted parameters like a javascript Date() object.  If it does then it is not permitted and it will destroy the object.

Comment: {"e":"kline","E":1671255706189,"s":"BTCUSDT","k":{"t":1671255660000,"T":1671255719999,"s":"BTCUSDT","i":"1m","f":2344537626,"L":2344539804,"o":"16694.81000000","c":"16701.40000000","h":"16702.56000000","l":"16692.71000000","v":"90.01706000","n":2179,"x":false,"q":"1503063.50982270","V":"60.36838000","Q":"1008045.00715330","B":"0"}}
this is the data in evt.data

Comment: What is in columnA of the `sh`