# Two data streams from different sources in one Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, websocket

[script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378549/running-websocket-in-google-sheet)

How can I get data using this script from two sources at once (for example, ALPACA and BINANACE) on one GOOGLE SHEETS page? I try to connect two sources at the same time, only one is connected, and a connection error occurs on the second output.

```
var wsUri = ("wss://stream.data.alpaca.markets/v2/sip");
  <? var myparam3000 = param3000(); ?>
  <? var myparam4000 = param4000(); ?>
  var nbr=0
  
  var wsUri2 = ("wss://api.alor.ru/ws");
  <? var myparam = param(); ?>
  <? var myparam2 = param2(); ?>
  var nbr=0
```