# GraphQL subscriptions via Websockets on GAE Standard not responding

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a GraphQL Server (based on [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-yoga), Node, Express) on Google AppEngine with the standard environment.

It uses a websocket endpoint to provide real-time subscriptions to database changes, which works perfectly on my local machine, but is not responding at all when deployed on the GAE instance.

Could it be because of another limitation of GAE standard?

Comment: Donno about NodeJS, but for python the standard environment doesn't allow listening sockets, see [Limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions_if_lang_is_java_java_7_runtime_only_endif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Dan Cornilescu, WebSockets are not (yet) supported in the App Engine Standard environment.

There is open a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35886348) for this to be supported and I suggest you to follow on the updates there.

Please take a look at Stack Overflow thread: [How can I run a WebSocket server on top of GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114902/how-can-i-run-a-websocket-server-on-top-of-gae) as well.