# Objectify - iOS - Android - Refresh chat UI when a new message is sent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

What is a good way to make a chat application between two people using Objectify and Google Datastore?

The main question I have is how can you have a mobile client (iOS/Android) screen refresh itself when a new message is sent? Such as in the following screen:

[image]

The main option I see is to send a push notification to the client that a new message has been sent, so query the datastore for new messages.

Web-sockets don't seem to be supported on Google App Engine from what I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114902/3075340). Or if they are they seem buggy?

What other options are there?

Answer (score 1):

It's technically possible, but it's a terrible idea. You would have to poll, which would scale poorly and kill your clients' battery life.

The datastore is the wrong tool for this job. Look for the highest level API that will do what you want, ideally something websocket-oriented like Firebase.