# Is there a way to develop a websocket client on the google cloud(appengine or cloud function etc..)?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, google-cloud-functions

I'm now looking for a way how to implement the websocket client on the google cloud except for GCE.

Let me Briefly introduce the goal.

Environment : javascript, nodejs, google cloud(cloud function or app engine)
My program works as the websocket client data that I want to get should be only transferred via websocket (websocket server: service provider, client: my program).The program will be running with scheduler, which should be automatically executed(out of browser) after getting the data, program should be terminated.

I think that this case is not normally used, because the websocket client is normally running on the browser.

However, I must use the google cloud platform with cloud function and app engine, not compute engine. We don't have any available local machine so the cloud platform should be used. In order to use cloud function and app engine, we just pay for it when we call it. It will be able to save the money.

However, I can't find the way to implement websocket client on the cloud platform. Because, cloud function and app engine are not compatible for the websocket and I always failed
So, could you advise how to develop the web socket client with google cloud platform?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (for standard environment) as is already answered on several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115214/11529321), the only way to have websockets over App Engine is using the Flexible environment but maybe is a little bit more expensive than STD ENV.

I found this official Google [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity) to use web-sockets on Flexible ENV

Maybe the best way to save money is using an always free Compute Engine VM

As stated in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits)

You can use an always-free **f1-micro** instance, this instance is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month, which means that if you use 2 instances you can only use them half the month for free.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I already saw the similar questions and answers with the document that you mentioned. In fact, my program needs just couple of minute for completion, as it is a client. So the Flexible ENV is very much huge for me. However, if I can do forced shutdonw the gae after finishing the requirement, it will be good for me

Comment: It isn't a good idea, enable and disable the GAE service, because the process take some minutes and when you shutdown your GAE service is not possible hit the URL.

maybe you gonna need more steps and use some additional services like Cloud functions.

I think that the only cheaper way to have websockets is using a free GCE VM.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest something like https://www.emitter.dev/ (disclosure: I'm the creator). Basically, you subscribe to whatever `WebSocket` you want and specify where we should `POST` to.